# How can I pass a variable in the optional part of a Python Behave regex expression?

Tags: regex, python-behave

I have a Behave test step that contains an optional time component.

This is the test step without the optional component:

```
Scenario: A user can create, validate, and delete a full session (DELETE /full/:user_id)
  When I create a session with userID 6ac0d2a2-3fa0-41bb-ba3d-ffdcf95f73f2 and companyID 9ca7ef6e-790e-4f7d-8b6c-1179c49294ec
```

This is the test step with the optional component:

```
Scenario: A user cannot validate an existing but expired full session (GET / )
  When I create a session with userID 6ac0d2a2-3fa0-41bb-ba3d-ffdcf95f73f2 and companyID 9ca7ef6e-790e-4f7d-8b6c-1179c49294ec and set the expiration time to 1 second
```

This is the corresponding function:

```
@when('I create a session with userID (?P<user_id>.*) and companyID (?P<company_id>.*)(?: and set the expiration time to (?P<seconds>\d+) second)?')
def send_request(context, user_id, company_id, seconds):
    url = context.session_url + "/full"
    body = {
        "userId": user_id,
        "companyId": company_id
    }

    print(seconds)
    # if specifying the expiration time instead of using the defaults:
    if seconds:
        body["maxAge"] = "PT1S"
        body["maxIdle"] = "PT1S"
```

When I run the test step with the optional parameter, the `seconds` variable is not passed into the function and evaluates as `None`. How can I change the regex to pass in the number specified in the Gherkin .feature file?

Comment: This seems similar https://stackoverflow.com/a/53766581/8291949

Answer (score 0):

The greedy quantifier `*` is used in `(?P<company_id>.*)`, resulting in:

```py
'company_id': '9ca7ef6e-790e-4f7d-8b6c-1179c49294ec and set the expiration time to 1 second',
'seconds': None,
'user_id': '6ac0d2a2-3fa0-41bb-ba3d-ffdcf95f73f2'
```

Use the lazy quantifier `*?` as in `(?P<company_id>.*?)`, resulting in:

```py
'company_id': '9ca7ef6e-790e-4f7d-8b6c-1179c49294ec',
'seconds': '1',
'user_id': '6ac0d2a2-3fa0-41bb-ba3d-ffdcf95f73f2'
```